# WebPack SockJS fails to construct due to the following error: "An insecure SockJS connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS"

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

I updated modules for my website project via **npm** and tried to access my site, as usual, through Chrome web browser at "https://127.0.0.1:8000"

Once the site loaded I received the following error:

> sockjs.js:689 Uncaught Error: SecurityError: An insecure SockJS connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS

Here's the full error stack trace:

```
Uncaught Error: SecurityError: An insecure SockJS connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS
at new SockJS (sockjs.js:689)
at new SockJSClient (webpack:///(:8000/webpack)-dev-server/client/clients/SockJSClient.js?:39:18)
at initSocket (webpack:///(:8000/webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js?:20:12)
at Object.eval (webpack:///(:8000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:176:1)
at eval (webpack:///(:8000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:177:30)
at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:8081 (bundle.9c58b1f21bf6b7e8db3b.js:9362)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.9c58b1f21bf6b7e8db3b.js:727)
at fn (bundle.9c58b1f21bf6b7e8db3b.js:101)
at eval (webpack:///multi_(:8000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:1:1)
at Object.0 (bundle.9c58b1f21bf6b7e8db3b.js:10997)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to have https configured in your webpack.config.js
look  [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps)

```
module.exports = {
        //...
    devServer: {
        https: {
           key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.key'),
           cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.crt'),
           ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem'),
         }
       }
    };
```